# Add freeze/lock authority for NFTs created with candy machine

Tags: metaplex, nft, candy-machine-v3

I am trying to create an NFT with [Candy machine](https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine) using [candy machine npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine).  I want to set the freeze authority to the creator of the NFT to allow the NFT creator to disable transfer functionality. How can I achieve this?